# console.log not working in arrow function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrow-functions

I have declared a arrow function inside react component. inside this i have logged a value but it shows error. I am new in react so please help me out.

Where I have declared the function

```
class DeliveryPage extends Component{
   onChange : (event) => { console.log('change', event.target.value); }
}
```

I have invoked the function here

```
  <ComboBox
    data={source}
    onChange={this.onChange}
    onFilterChange={this.onFilterChange}
    filterable={true}
  />
```

[image: My output]

Then i have changed my code to

```
    onChange = (event) => { console.log('change', event.target.value); }
```

[image: After change this error occurs]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
onChange : (event) => { console.log('change', event.target.value); }
```

This is incorrect syntax, it should be:

```
onChange = (event) => { console.log('change', event.target.value); }
```

---

If the Arrow Functions don't work, then you most likely don't have the *proposal-class-properties* functionally, which can be installed via the following Babel Plugin: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties.

Otherwise, try this method similar to this:

```
class DeliveryPage extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }

  onChange(event) {
    console.log('change', event.target.value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Then you probably need this babel plugin: [link](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties)

Comment: Hmm did you install React using `create-react-app`. Do you know if you actually support this experimental feature?

Comment: I am integrated it to asp .net project

Answer (score 0):

You should be trying this

```
class DeliveryPage extends Component{
   onChange = (event) => {
     console.log('change', event.target.value);
  }
}
```